# how can i select all the lis and then add all its numbers together?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, input, selector

```
  <div id=“container”> 
<!--i want to select all the li and the add all their numbers together -->
            <ul> 
                <li>5</li> 
                <li>10</li> 
                <li>15</li> 
                <li class="child">20</li> 
                <li>25</li> 
                <li>30</li> 
                <li>25</li> 
                <li>30</li> 
                 <li>25</li> 
                <li>30</li> 
                <li>25</li> 
                <li>30</li>
            </ul> 
    </div>
```

i want to select all the li and the add all their numbers together
i want to select all the li and the add all their numbers together

Comment: you use a selector with a loop , and a operator

Comment: If it’s one time operation ups can open the html in a browser, copy and paste as text into excel, then use sum function there.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the function `document.querySeclectorAll` and the function reduce for adding the values.

```js
let result = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('#container li')).reduce((a, {textContent}) => a + +textContent, 0);
console.log(result);
```

```html
<div id="container">  <!--i want to select all the li and the add all their numbers together -->  <ul>    <li>5</li>    <li>10</li>    <li>15</li>    <li class="child">20</li>    <li>25</li>    <li>30</li>    <li>25</li>    <li>30</li>    <li>25</li>    <li>30</li>    <li>25</li>    <li>30</li>  </ul></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `querySelectorAll()` and `forEach()`

```js
var sum = 0;
document.querySelectorAll('#container ul > li').forEach(function(el){
  sum += Number(el.textContent);
});
console.log(sum);
```

```html
<div id="container"> 
  <ul> 
      <li>5</li> 
      <li>10</li> 
      <li>15</li> 
      <li class="child">20</li> 
      <li>25</li> 
      <li>30</li> 
      <li>25</li> 
      <li>30</li> 
       <li>25</li> 
      <li>30</li> 
      <li>25</li> 
      <li>30</li>
  </ul> 
</div>
```

Comment: @Kobe this example is easier to understand for those who started learning js though

Comment: Fair enough @Mamun

Answer (score 0):

Use a `NodeList` to iterate through by using `getElementsByTagName()`:

```
var lis = document.getElementById("container").getElementsByTagName("li");
```

Iterate over the list like one would over an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
let li = [...document.querySelectorAll('#container ul > li')]; //
let counter = 0; //the sum of all li

li.forEach(el => {
    counter += el.textContent * 1;
});
```

Comment: Although this code snippet may answer the question, including an explanation of *why* and *how* it helps solve the problem improves the quality and longevity of your answer. See ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).